# Multiple Processes Transmit Over Sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have created a C++ server process in Linux that sends large data packet (>140kb each at 4Hz) via TCP/IP to client program and this data packet is required to send < 1.5 seconds.

All seems okay with 1 server and 1 client. However, when I executed more than 5 instances of the server process at the same time and each process handles its own client, there seems to be delay (>10 secs) in the socket writing by each process.

I calculated the maximum network bandwidth that will appear in the network per second:

- 1 instance  of client = 0.56MB / sec,
- 2 instances of client = 1.12MB / sec,
- 3 instances of client = 1.68MB / sec,
- 4 instances of client = 2.24MB / sec,
- 5 instances of client = 2.80MB / sec,

and so on.

First of all, is the above feasible if my network is 100Mbps? My receiving client programs are running in Windows OS.

Is there anything I need to configure in my socket programming and in my sender/receiver OS?

Comment: Maybe collisions in the cable?